# Differentiate between the program setting a checkbox and the user clicking it

Tags: c#, checkbox

I want to know if there is a way to differentiate between the user clicking a checkbox, in which case I would like the following event to trigger, and the program itself setting the checked state, in which case I would like it to do nothing.

```
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sList.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
                CList[sList.SelectedIndex]._object[1] += 8;
            else
                CList[sList.SelectedIndex]._object[1] -= 8;
        }
    }
```

I just can't seem to find much about this issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you are doing the check event programmatically, remove the association with the handler and after checking set back the handler again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also handle the click event of the checkbox. I don't know if that event is fired before or after checkedchanged, but if it happens before you could set a boolean to true or something and read it in checkedchanged.